# Android design icons in 256x256

Tags: android, icons

I am looking to use these icons in my app

http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

But the problem is that these are only available in small sizes(~64x64) and if i try to expand it using some online tools, then they become very blurry. Is there any way to get these icons in 256x256 size or enlarging these icons but without blurring?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It *IS* possible. But it requires some work.
The icons are distributed with an .ai file (like `All_Icons.ai`), which the extension for Adobe Illustrator image file.
Each icon is in its own layer in that file.

Adobe Illustrator is a vector image software, I mean it's not a bitmap image, so it can be enlarged without losing quality to any size.

However, it also means you need a software that can handle .ai file.

If you have Adobe Illustrator, open the .ai file, and find the layer that you want, go to layer menu and select "hide other layers", and save the image for web. In the saving for web dialog, you can select the image size for png, jpg, or gif file. (you can change the color or opacity if you need)

Answer (score 1):

There is an accompanying .ai (Adobe Illustrator) file which has Vector images for all the .png's that are included in the various downloads. And since they are Vectors, you can resize them to your liking without worrying about distortion or pixelation.

Alternatively, you can generate your image resources using the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html), specifically, the [Generic Icons](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example) option in the Android Asset Studio. They use the same Icons that you find on the Android Downloads page. *I haven't compared if they are the exact number of images though*.

A note about the Android Asset Studio (*Generic Icons*) though. You can only generate image resources in **dp** sizes and **not px** as you want them to be. That can be mitigated by using this converter here: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can't enlarge smaller images, this will always result in the loss of quality. Try finding similar images with 256x256 resolution.